# Using echo to display a php variable within html isn't working

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I just want to apologize for my English in advance, it isn't my native language. For school I have to build a website with a linked database. So far I have managed to build a database and I wrote some php and html pages but I'm kind of stuck right now. My problem is that I'm using php within an html page, and in that php I'm trying to display the results of my query, but the result in the html page is just this:

```
voornaam email ?> $voornaam . $row['email'].;} ?> ";?>
```

My full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html> 
<head>
<title>SneekDate</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stijl8.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<BODY background="foto_drie.jpg">

<div id="header">Profielen</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href=home.html>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=register.html>Direct aanmelden!</a></li>
<li><a href=login.html>Inloggen</a></li>
<li><a href=profielen.html>Profielen</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<?php 
echo <table border = 1>
<tr>
<th>voornaam</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>
?>

<?php
require('login.php');
require('connect.php');

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `persoon_gegevens` WHERE email = '$email'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
$voornaam = $row['voornaam'];
?>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{   
    echo 
    <tr>
    <td> $voornaam</td>
    <td> . $row['email'] . </td>
    </tr>;
}
?>

<?php
echo "</table>";
?>


<div id="footer">
&copy; SneekDate, uit Sneek...
Pas op! Deelname vanaf 18 jaar!
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your PHP had display_errors and error_reporting on, you'd have been told about your PHP syntax errors.

Comment: With all these syntax errors, you shouldn't be getting any output at all. It should just fail and send a blank page. Are you sure the script has a `.php` extension?

Comment: Please consider using PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql_* functions as they are depreciated and vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing quotes around your string:

```
echo <table border = 1>
```

should be

```
echo '<table border = 1>
<tr>
<th>voornaam</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>';
```

Comment: Same issue exists in the `while` loop.

Comment: Good/smart move on the wiki ;)

Comment: Yeah. Didn't want rep for such a silly thing. Especially since I voted to close.

Comment: Silly is to putty, as wiki is to pedia.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply. I did what you said: I put quotes around my echo code, but my html page is still displaying $voornaam and . $row['email'] . .I just figured out that when i run the php script alone (so outside of the html code), it works perfectly. It just won't work inside the html code

Comment: Does that file have a .php extension?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mix variables and strings you can either use quotation marks and the dot notation to concatenate eg

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $voornaam . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Or parenthesis e.g.

```
echo "<tr><td>$voornaam</td><td>{$row['email']}</td>/tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some quotes in 2 places

1)

```
echo "<table border = 1>
<tr>
<th>voornaam</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>";
```

2)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{   
    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $voornaam . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply. I did what you said: I put quotes around my echo code, but my html page is still displaying $voornaam and . $row['email'] . .I just figured out that when i run the php script alone (so outside of the html code), it works perfectly. It just won't work inside the html code